# Sending params dynamic[] values to method

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

In the app I'm working on, a former developer created a method that expects `params dynamic[]` parameters. I'm familiar with `dynamic` but not sure how to send parameters to this function.

The method I'm trying to call looks like this:

```
public async Task CallDbStoredProcedure(string procedureId, string collectionName, params dynamic[] spParameters)
{
   // Makes stored procedure call to Cosmos Db
}
```

I assume he used `dynamic` because each parameter can be of different type which is the case in my particular scenario.

I need to send two parameters:

- `@itemId` which is a `Guid` value
- `@statusId` which is an `int` value

How do I create this `params dynamic[]` with my parameter values so that I can send it to the `CallDbStoredProcedure()` method?

Comment: they could have used `params Object?[]` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create anything: `params` parameters arrays are created implicitly by the compiler:

```
Guid  itemId   = new Guid( "5fb75eac-9f0b-550c-339f-fc21fde966cd" );
Int32 statusId = 123;

await CallDbStoredProcedure( procedureId: "PerformPhilately", collectionName: "my stamp collection", itemId, statusId );
```

But if you *really* wanted to, you can also do this:

```
dynamic[] arr = new dynamic[] { itemId, statusId };

await CallDbStoredProcedure( procedureId: "PerformPhilately", collectionName: "my stamp collection", spParameters: arr );
```

...but this is generally inadvisable because with `params` arrays, the callee method generally assumes ownership of the array (and so can mutate it) whereas if the caller has a named reference to it (especially in an `async` call-site), they could do a rug-pull.

Comment: Thank you! Both approaches you suggested work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of dynamic objects to represent your parameters and then pass them to the CallDbStoredProcedure method. Here's an example using your specific scenario:
Guid itemId = Guid.NewGuid();
int statusId = 42;

```
dynamic[] parameters = new dynamic[]
{
    itemId,
    statusId
};

await CallDbStoredProcedure("YourProcedureId", "YourCollectionName", parameters);
```

Make sure to replace "YourProcedureId" and "YourCollectionName" with the actual values you need for the procedureId and collectionName parameters of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to call it. dynamic parameters of any type and any length can be passed to this method like

```
CallDbStoredProcedure("procedureId", "collectionName", 1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c");
```